# ics file DTEND time or timezone

Tags: timezone, icalendar

When I open my ics file on an android device, the DTSTART date is showing the right time, but the DTENDis showing the wrong time (+1 hour). When I open the ics directly on google calendar or outlook the DTEND date is correctly shown. Why doesn't this work??

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0
PRODID:TEST
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID: 20150217T011243-1175262756
DTSTAMP: 20150217T011243
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20150301T120000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20150301T200000
SUMMARY:Werken
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

N.B. If I remove the TZID from DTSTART and DTEND both start and endtime will show +1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because your calendar does not define a `VTIMEZONE` (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.5)